# Why is my Arduino and P5.js serial connection an equation?

Tags: javascript, arduino, serial-port, p5.js

I found out that whatever I get in the p5.js sketch as a serial read is one value (52)  minus the second value (48) and then multiplied by 10. This would equal 40 which is the serial output set on the Arduino. I am using the p5.serialcontrol application to build a connection from the browser to the serial port:

```js
let serial;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  serial = new p5.SerialPort();
  serial.open("COM3");
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  let data = serial.read();
  
  console.log(data);// prints 48 then 52 repeateadly
}
```

Comment: Serial.print converts the number to text. ASCII code for '4' is 52. The ASCII codes for digits are in a group which starts with '0' (ASCII code 48)

Comment: @Felix Welcome! The question is great except one minor caveat: it's recommended you post the code as a Code Sample (`{}` button or Ctrl+K / CMD + K shortcut). Ideally, in your case, since you're using Arduino code it might help to paste that code as well: this may provide more information on how you're sending data over serial (e.g. `Serial.print()` / `Serial.println()`  / `Serial.write()`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All digital values and digital signals are just bits, that can be represented and interpreted as numbers (e.g. binary, octal, decimal or hexadecimal). Even text characters are usually stored and transmitted as bits. ASCII is one of the most common translation tables between characters and numeric values.

`48` is the ASCII value for character `'0'` and `52` is the ASCII value for character `'4'`. The Arduino is sending the string `"40"` in a loop and the other side is receiving the numeric ASCII values `48` and `52` in a loop.

The other side doesn't know the data type. It only receives bits. You have to tell the program to interpret these bits as ASCII encoded characters.